# VueJs How to flicker only updated data like Chrome dev tool paint flashing

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, transition

There is explanation in a manual [How to use transition animation in Vue](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html).

I can use six classes for enter/leave transition.

It works when I manipulate data like below.

```
example.list.push({data:"new data"})
example.list.splice(0,1,{data:"new data"})
```

I would like to update my data like below. And have an effect on updated data only like Chrome dev tool paint flashing.

```
example.list[0].data = "new data"
```

I can use splice to put transition animation on updated data only but I don't want to update whole list again(DOM Update). splice casues whole list DOM update.

---

**more elaborate explanation.
What I expected and What I want to make is that only apply some css effect on updated data. the code for explanation is down below(only having transition effect on first row td size value).**

html

```
<id="testApp">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>size</th>
        <th>weight</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody is="transition-group" name="fade">
      <tr is="test-component"
        v-for="item in itemList"
        v-bind:name="item.name"
        v-bind:size="item.size"
        v-bind:weight="item.weight"
        v-bind:key="item.id">
      </tr>
    </tbody>  
  </table>
</div>

<template id="test-component">
  <tr>
    <td>{{name}}</td>
    <td>{{size}}</td>
    <td>{{weight}}</td>
  </tr>
</template>
```

script

```
Vue.component('test-component', {
  template: '#test-component',
  props: {
    name: String,
    size: Number,
    weight: Number
  }
})

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#testApp',
  data: {
    itemList: [
      {id:0, name: 'A', size:1, weight:10},
      {id:1, name: 'B', size:2, weight:50}
    ]
  }
})

setInterval(function() {
  Vue.set(app.itemList, 0, {id:0, name:'A', size:3, weight:10 }); 
}, 3000)
```

css

```
.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity .5s;
}
.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: `this.$set(this.example.list, 0, obj);` should work for you. https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set

Comment: How can i use enter/leave transition with this Vue set method? enter/leave transition was applied to element when I pushed or spliced list.